# Dart - set method not defined

Tags: oop, dart, getter-setter

I have two classes that work with each other, but some reason the set method in one of the classes is not considered defined in the other class. I am currently learning Dart (via Flutter), so I am wondering if I might be missing something.

```dart
class ClassA {
    List<ClassB> _bunchOfClassBs = [];

    void doSomething() {
        for(ClassB foo in _bunchOfClassBs) {
            foo.addCount('bar'); // Undefined method
        }
    }
}

class ClassB {
    int_counting = 0;

    set addCount(int number) => _counting += number;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling setter incorrectly, should be:

```
foo.addCount = 123;
```

And for setters, name should not be `addCount` but `count`

Comment: The life of a polyglot and used to things being surrounded in (). Thanks!

By the way, the addCount was just an example, but i'll keep your other suggestion in mind.